# Azure DevOps "The user doesn't have access to the variable groups added to this pipeline or they are not found. IDs: 3"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-pipeline

**Issue:**

"The user doesn't have access to the variable groups added to this pipeline or they are not found. IDs: 3"

**When this happens:**

- Migrating a Pipeline in "Json" format from "Azure DevOps On-premise 2020" towards "Azure DevOps Cloud".
- When saving all changes is complaining that no access for the user towards "Variables Groups" that seems to be counter-intuitive because those were created with my user while doing the Import, i.e did create the same "Variables and Values" for the consumption of the Pipeline

**Solutions Offered and Applied:**

Some documentation indicated to do the next:
"So you just need to add "Project Collection Build Service(xxx)" account as Administrator role for the variable group."
[image]

I followed this and added the "Project Collection Build Service" from "read" to "Administrator" but the same error output is presented.

Comment: Have you recreate the variable groups in the target project with the same variables and manually fix the pipelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**State:**
Solved

**Solution Details:**

It seems MS/Azure DevOps hashed each link to a variable group dependant on the Collection, so when migration takes place the current links migrated are completely useless,
The right action would be in that sense to undo the links are re-create them from scratch again.

This will save a lot of time for other folks with the same issue, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is not definitively an answer, but one thing to check is whether or not access is allowed to all pipelines:

[image: AllowAccess]

I don't see that checkbox in your screenshot. If `Allow access to all pipelines` is not set, or not settable, Microsoft recommend manually queueing a build - if there's a resource authorization error, you should be able to select it and authorize access to the pipeline that's being executed.

Comment: Hello @WaitingForGuacamole, thanks for the effort and time helping a fellow user,
That option was already "enabled" therefore isn't the solution for this case